# replace relative src img with full url php

Tags: php, regex

I have fetched an HTML page,How i can replace relative img src with these URLs absolute?

In my content html:

```
<img width="23" height="23" class="img" src="/static/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">

<img width="23" height="23" class="img" src="/static/img/tw.png" alt="tw">
```

(Paths not stable)

```
<img width="130" =="" height="200" alt="" src="http://otherdomain/files/ads/00905819.gif">
```

in html contents i have other images src with absolute src,i want change only relative src images.
ex :

```
  <img width="23" height="23" class="img" src="/static/img/facebook.png"    alt="Facebook">
  <img width="23" height="23" class="img" src="/images/xx.png" alt="xxx">
```

to

```
<img width="23" height="23" class="img" src="http://example.com/static/img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
```

My preg_replace:

```
$html = preg_replace("(]*src\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)", '$1http://www.example.com$2$3', $x1);
```

But this replace all images src

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code, 
it should work in your case.

```
$html = str_replace('src="/static', 'src="http://example.com/static', $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your relative path always starts with `'/static/img/'` then you can use simple `str_replace` function instead of regexp.

For example:

```
$html = str_replace('src="/static/img/', 'src="http://example.com/static/img/', $html);
```

Comment: Thanks,But path not stable